# media queries for device-pixel-ratio not working

Tags: css, less, media-queries

My media queries in **LESS** are working fine on the desktop, but not when testing an iPad2 or Samsung Galaxy 4 phone, and it seems to be `device-pixel-ratio` that's throwing things off.  I lowered the `min-device-pixel-ratio` to 1.5.  That didn't work either.  For some reason, the Samsung and iPad both reach into the same queries, despite the Samsungs 640x320 resolution and the iPad's 1024x768 resolution.  Any idea how I can break out these media queries better?

**LESS code:**

```
@screenXS:~"screen and (max-width:479px)";
@screenS:~"screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width:639px)";
@screenM:~"screen and (min-width: 640px) and (max-width:767px)";
@screenL:~"screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width:1023px)";
@screenXL:~"screen and (min-width: 1024px)";
@dpr:~"(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2) and (min-device-pixel-ratio:2)";

.myElement {
     @media @screenXS {
          font-size: 10px;
          line-height: 18px;
          @media @dpr {
                color:#f00 !important;
                font-size:20px;
          }
     }
     @media @screenS {
          font-size: 11px;
          line-height: 20px;
          @media @dpr {
                color:#0f0 !important;
                font-size:30px;
          }
     }
     @media @screenM, @screenL {
          font-size: 12px;
          line-height: 21px;
          @media @dpr {
                color:#00f !important;
                font-size:50px;
          }
     }
     @media @screenXL {
          font-size: 14px;
          line-height: 25px;
          @media @dpr {
                color:#ff0 !important;
                font-size:100px;
          }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Assuming they both fall into `[640...1023]`, media does not this just mean that iPad's orientation during your tests is portrait? (i.e. `768x1024` instead of `1024x768`).

Comment: No.  The issue I'm having is that I'm seeing the same media queries get used for the phone and the iPad.  They should be using different media queries, I believe.

Comment: Please re-read what I wrote. They may use the same media query *if* "iPad's orientation during your tests is portrait" thus they both fall into the `@screenM, @screenL` media. At least I don't see any other reason why they would otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this :)

```
<link href="css/mobile_portrait.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (orientation: portrait)">
<link href="css/mobile_landscape.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (orientation: landscape)">
<link href="css/tablet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-width: 769px)">
<link href="css/netbook.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-width: 1024px)">
<link href="css/desktop.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-width: 1224px)">
```

it's only an example!